# NullPointerException when getting Page Information

Tags: java, pdf, itext, itext7

I need to detect the page orientations of my PDF document. Doing so I'm trying to get the page sizes of the single pages:

```
pdfGen = createPdf.makePdf("doc.pdf");
document = pdfGen.getDocument();
document.setMargins(80, 80, 80, 80);
writer = pdfGen.getWriter();

document.add(new Paragraph("some content"));

document.add(new AreaBreak(PageSize.A4.rotate()));
document.add(new Paragraph("more content"));

document.add(new AreaBreak(PageSize.A4));
document.add(new Paragraph("even more content"));

Rectangle rect = document.getPdfDocument().getPage(1).getPageSizeWithRotation(); // e.g. the 1st page

document.close();
writer.close();
```

But all I get is a `NullPointerException` in this line: `Rectangle rect = document.getPdfDocument().getPage(1).getPageSizeWithRotation()`.

---

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDictionary.get(PdfDictionary.java:456)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDictionary.getAsArray(PdfDictionary.java:156)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfPage.getMediaBox(PdfPage.java:516)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfPage.getPageSize(PdfPage.java:125)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfPage.getPageSizeWithRotation(PdfPage.java:134)
    at com.myPackage.MyClass.myFunc(MyClass.java:15)
// ...
```

Comment: You don't have a page 1

Comment: @JEY: I don't think that's the problem. When I comment out that line, the document generates without any errors and with all 3 pages. That's the weird thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because the immediate flush mode is enabled.

Either save the needed information beforehands or use a three-arguments constructor to create a document:

```
Document document = new Document(pdfDoc, PageSize.A4, true);
```

As it's stated in the documentation for `immediateFlush`: *if true, write pages and page-related instructions to the {@link PdfDocument} as soon as possible.* That's done to decrease the memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

One of the following is null:

- `document`
- `document.getPdfDocument()`
- `document.getPdfDocument().getPage(1)`

My guess it's probably the last one, but you should check them all out.

You might also find using [the `getFirstPage()` method](http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext7/7.0.7/com/itextpdf/kernel/pdf/PdfDocument.html#getFirstPage--) means you don't get confused if the first page is 0 or 1 indexed.

Comment: I don't think that's the problem. When I comment out that line, the document generates without any errors and with all 3 pages.